# Segmentation fault in mac but not other online compilers

Tags: c++, macos

This code runs on ideone and other compilers but gives segmentation fault in my mac or some junk values. Please help. This is standard in order traversal and should just print 1 to 7.

https://ideone.com/l5tkks

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

typedef struct node* Node;

Node insert(Node root, int num){
    if(root==NULL){
        Node newNode=(Node)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode->data=num;
        newNode->left=NULL;
        newNode->right=NULL;
        return newNode;
    }

    if(root->data>num)
        root->left=insert(root->left,num);
    else
        root->right=insert(root->right,num);
    return root;
}

void printinorder(Node root){
    if(root==NULL)
        return;

    printinorder(root->left);
    cout<<root->data<<endl;
    printinorder(root->right);
}

int main(){
    Node tree=NULL;
    tree=insert(tree,1);
    tree=insert(tree,2);
    tree=insert(tree,3);
    tree=insert(tree,4);
    tree=insert(tree,5);
    tree=insert(tree,6);
    tree=insert(tree,7);
    printinorder(tree);
}
```

Comment: Your typedeffing of a pointer type is obscuring the bug. Remove the typedef and spell out the types. (And if you want to learn C++, learn C++ instead of C.)

Comment: note: "<some> fault in X but not Y" always indicates undefined behaviour - i.e. an invalid program. Never ignore this signal.

Comment: Thanks molbdnilo. I was practicing trees for a coding interview. Otherwise I use c++ only.

Comment: Is there a special reason you are using `malloc`  and not `new`?

Comment: Yes, I should have used new. Sorry. No particular reason to use malloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Node newNode = (Node) malloc(sizeof(Node));
> ```

should be

```
Node newNode = (Node) malloc(sizeof(node));
```